# I want to convert a filter string from given string(sql server supported filter) format to linq acceptable filter format

Tags: c#, .net, linq

My string will look like -

```
"Industry" = "Information Technology" And "AdID" in ("5","3") And "Advertiser" = "Google"
```

I want this string to be in below format

```
Industry = "Information Technology" And AdID.Contains(5,3) And Advertiser = "Google"
```

Left-hand side double quotes(") should be removed and also from right-hand side double quotes from a numeric value. Also, it should convert `in` and `not in` to `abc.Contains()` and `!abc.Contains()`. Also want `is` and `is not` to `abc.Equals()` and `!abc.Equals()` respectively.

I tried by splitting the string into parts and modify and replace but yet not found any proper solution.

Comment: I hope you realise that `AdID in ("5", "3")` is not the same as `AdID.Contains(5,3)`

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible. You could split the string in different ways. First I would split the string with each logic gate type (and, or).

You can do that like this:

```
string data = "\"Industry\" = \"Information Technology\" And \"AdID\" in (\"5\",\"3\") And \"Advertiser\" = \"Google\"";

var output = data.Split(new string[] { "And" , "Or"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

The output from this will be an array of strings. But you also need to then know the index of each "and" and "or", so you know what gate type is to be considered for each string in the output array. If you only have cases with "and" it becomes easier as you can use a regular split and you will not have to take the logic gate type into account.

This will also require the use of regex to find different patterns like the collection:

"AdID" in ("5","3")

If you find a way to recognize this pattern it could be made into something like:

```
(new string[] {"1","2", "3"}).Contains("1")
```

The more special cases and the less defined the SQL code the harder this will be to do. So it would help if you can ensure that f.ex. "and" is always "And" or "AND" and that a collection is always defined f.ex. like ("5","3") and not like ("5" , " 3") and otherwise changing the format and style of how the SQL is written. If you can ensure this, parsing it will be much easier.

You ask 
'Left-hand side double quotes(") should be removed and also from right-hand side double quotes from a numeric value'
This can be done using regex but a bit too advanced for me to do.
If you do the C# would instead be:

```
(new int[] {1,2, 3}).Contains(1)
```

Comment: (new int[] {1,2,3}).Contains(1) this is also not accepted by Dynamic Linq.

Comment: Pretty sure it should? Or by Dynamic Linq you mean a type of Linq other than the Linq you would usually use in some class?

Example:

string[] newCollecton = {"1","2", "3"};
  var collect = newCollecton.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).Where(y => (new int[] {1,2, 3}).ToList().Contains(y));